# Concise way to compile dynamically created regexp

Tags: regex, perl

I want to dynamically create a compiled regexp. Well, no problem:

```
my $rx = join('|', keys %replacement_hash);
```

I want to compile it to avoid overhead on repeated calls. No problem as well:

```
$rx = qr/$rx/;
```

What is problem though - it is too long for such a trivial operation. Two lines and two extra times I need to mention variable name, so I'd need to change it in all 3 positions if I decide to rename it.

So far I've come with either using a helper function (which still would have disadvantages of having to keep this function somewhere):

```
sub qr_expr { qr/$_[0]/ }
# and later
my $rx = qr_expr(join('|', keys %replacement_hash));
```

or just plainly inlining the same function where I need it:

```
my $rx = sub{qr/$_[0]/}->(join('|', keys %replacement_hash));
```

Is there a way to write it more concisely?

Comment: you could use [`map`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/map.html): `my ($rx) = map { qr/$_/ } join('|', keys %replacement_hash)`.

Comment: @HunterMcMillen, good one! If only it didn't need extra context () arond `my` list...

Comment: map returns a list, if you only want to capture the first element (in this case there is only one element) you need to use parentheses, otherwise you will get the size of the list.

Comment: That last comment is inaccurate. "Returns a list" simply means "returns a number of values that can be different than one". If an operator did that in scalar context, Perl would crash. So saying that `map` returns a list is incorrect. In scalar context (as in `my $x = map ...`), `map` returns the number of values it *would have returned* in list context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
my ($re) = map qr/$_/, join '|', map quotemeta, @strings;
```

Chances are you don't need to compile it.

Most of the time, you end up embedding it in another pattern (e.g. `/^$re\z/` or `/($re)/`), forcing the pattern to be recompiled. (`/$re/` doesn't recompile, and neither does the equivalent `=~ $re`.)

Furthermore, Perl caches the compiled form of the last pattern it compiled. If it's asked to compile the same pattern again, it simply returns the cached copy instead.

In both of those situations, the following would suffice:

```
my $pat = join '|', map quotemeta, @strings;
```

Comment: While plain string is indeed pretty much on par with `qr//`, `/o` still seems to provide 5-10% increase to my surprise. I hoped we got rid of it long time ago.